# How to pass files to subproject in Meson Build system

Tags: build, meson-build

I am trying to use Meson as a build system for an embedded collection of C files, mainly an RTOS with some utility modules and drivers. The goal is to use this project as a library that can be linked to a user application.

This RTOS library needs to be configured: I need to pass it a bunch of header files that contains macros.

These macros mainly consist of small snippets of code that the RTOS uses to access the hardware.

For now I have configured my RTOS library as a meson project so I can use it as a subproject when needed.

I've seen that I can pass build options to a meson subproject. They can be eventually used to generate configuration files.

But the macros contain lines of code, I cannot convert them to build options.

Is there a way to pass header files directly to a meson subproject?